# Bash globbing and argument passing

Tags: bash, wildcards, arguments, glob

I have the following simplified bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

files=("$@")

if [ "X$files" = "X" ]; then
  files=$HOME/print/*.pdf;
fi

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  ls "$file";
done
```

If I pass arguments (file names) as parameters this script will print the proper file names. On the other hand, if I don't pass arguments, it will print

```
/home/user/print/*.pdf: No such file or directory
```

Why are the file names not expanded in this case, and how do I fix it? Note that I use the `files=("$@")` and `"${files[@]}"` constructs because I read that it is to be preferred over the usual "files=$*".

Comment: Where is `files=$*` ever _usual_? That's plain _wrong_.

Comment: Usual is relative, right. I meant a method which does not use arrays. What would you do then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're assigning `files` as a *scalar* variable instead of an *array* variable.

In

```
 files=$HOME/print/*.pdf
```

You're assigning some *string* like `/home/highsciguy/print/*.pdf` to the `$files` scalar (aka string) variable.

Use:

```
files=(~/print/*.pdf)
```

or

```
files=("$HOME"/print/*.pdf)
```

instead. The shell will expand that globbing pattern into a list of file paths, and assign each of them to elements of the `$files` *array*.

The expansion of the glob is done at the time of the assignment.

You don't have to use non-standard sh features, and you could use your system's `sh` instead of `bash` here by writing it:

```
#!/bin/sh -

[ "$#" -gt 0 ] || set -- ~/print/*.pdf

for file do
  ls -d -- "$file"
done
```

`set` is to assign the `"$@"` array of positional parameters.

Another approach could have been to store the *globbing pattern* in a scalar variable:

```
files=$HOME/print/*.pdf
```

And have the shell expand the glob at the time the `$files`  variable is expanded.

```
IFS= # disable word splitting
for file in $files; do ...
```

Here, because `$files` is not quoted (which you shouldn't usually do), its expansion is subject to word splitting (which we've disabled here) and globbing/filename generation.

So the `*.pdf`  will be expanded to the list of matching files. However, if `$HOME` contained wildcard characters, they could be expanded too, which is why it's still preferable to use an array variable.

Answer (score 4):

You may have seen things like `files=$*` and `files=~/print/*.pdf` in older shells without arrays, and then `ls $files`.

A variable substitution which is not within double quotes interprets the value of the variable as a whitespace-separated list of shell wildcard patterns which are replaced by matching file names if there are any. For example, after `files=~/print/*.pdf`, `ls $files` expands to something like `ls` with the arguments `/home/highsciguy/print/bar.pdf`, `/home/highsciguy/print/foo.pdf`, etc. In the case `files=$*`, this assignment concatenates the arguments passed to the script with spaces in between, and `ls $files` splits them back out.

All of this breaks down if you have file names containing whitespace or globbing characters, which is why you shouldn't do things this way. Use arrays instead.

```
files=("$@")
if ((${#files[@]} == 0)); then
  files=("$HOME"/print/*.pdf)
fi
```

Note that

- All array assignments require parentheses around the array values: `var=(…)`.
- To test whether an array is empty, check its length. `"$files"` is empty when `files` is an array whose element of index 0 is unset or an empty string. Also `[ "X$foo" = "X" ]` is an obsolete way to test whether `$foo` is empty: all modern shells implement `[ -n "$foo" ]` correctly. In bash, you can use `[[ -n $foo ]]`.

In shells that don't support arrays, there is in fact one array: the positional parameters to the shell or current function. Here, you don't really need the `files` array, in fact it would be easier to use the positional parameters.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  set -- ~/print/*.pdf
fi
for file do …
```